# Declaring private variable in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, private

I'm new to CI and I'm trying to access a private variable through the application, but I set a value to the variable, next time I try to access the function(that I called from a submit form in my view), the private variable that I had set is empty. Can someone help? thx

```
class Example extends CI_Controller{

    private $_variable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //value from database
        $this->_variable = 'somevalue';
    }

    //calling this function from a view
    public function some_method()
    {
        // code...
        // $this->_variable returning without any value
    }
}
```

Comment: How you calling some_method from your view.Add that calling part to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your views shouldn't directly try to access methods of your controller, instead, you should send those while calling the view in the second arg:

[See Codeigniter's docs related to this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) (I assume you're spanish, because you use "variable").

```
$args = Array( "var1" => "variable", "var2" => "variable" );
$this->load->view("some_url", $args);
```

Then $var1 and $var2 will be available in your view.

Comment: I edit the question. What I mean is, In my view I submitted a form and a function from the controller is executed, but the private variable that I set in the index() function is empty.

Comment: Variables does not persist, you should use sessions

(Codeigniter Sessions):
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Or php's Native Sessions (But these are a bit more complicated)

http://php.net/manual/es/oop4.magic-functions.php

Comment: So I think I gonna load this variable on my controller again. So this detail happens as a characteristic from MVC concept or is just codeigniter?

Comment: Normal php variables are suppossed to "live" until the page is served, so i think it can be understood as a native php concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your `some_method` is not actually a view. At best it could be a Example Controller function that will calling from a view. Your `index()` function is actually assigning the value in your private `$_variable`, so to pass the value to your view, you must first call the `index()` function to assign variable and the value will be available to your `some_method()`. Example of how you'll pass the variable to your view is given bellow.

```
    public function some_method()
    {

        return  $this->_variable;

    }
```

In Your view, to access the variable:

```
echo $this->some_method();
```

I believe this will help you to show your private variable in your view.